# Confusion about proof statement by implication

Tags: logic, proof-writing, alternative-proof, fake-proofs

I have a question regarding proving "*if p is true then q is true*".

One way, is to show p $\implies$ q is a true statement, so then if p is true, then q is true.

The other way is to prove it by contrapositive, which is to say $\neg$q $\implies$ $\neg$p is true. This can be shown from the truth table of $\neg$q $\implies$ $\neg$p and p $\implies$ q, which proves they are logically equivalent.

| p | q | (p $\implies$ q) | ($\neg$q $\implies$ $\neg$p) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | T | T |
| F | T | T | T |
| T | F | F | F |
| T | T | T | T |

However, if p is true there are more logically equivalent statements on restriction of the case p = T . For example, let's look at $\neg$(p $\implies$$\neg$q).

| p | q | ~(p $\implies$ ~q) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | F |
| F | T | F |
| T | F | F |
| T | T | T |

If you restrict $\neg$(p $\implies$ $\neg$q) truth table to the case that p=T (as we only aim to show if p=T then q = T) , it is equivalent to p $\implies$ q truth table when p=T.

So why can't we just say if we want to prove "*if p is true then q is true*", we first show (p $\implies$ $\neg$q) is false, which means $\neg$(p $\implies$ $\neg$q) is true. and now if p=T it's truth table is the same as p $\implies$ q, so it means q is true.

So can use this approach alongside direct proof (p -> q) and prove by contrapositive ($\neg$q $\implies$ $\neg$p) when you only need to show if p is true the q is true?

I really appreciate any help with this confusion. Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $\lnot Q \Rightarrow \lnot P$ is not proof by contradiction, but a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: I'll fix it, Thanks for the comments Shaun and soupless :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the approach of showing $\neg (p \to \neg q)$ as opposed to $\neg q \to \neg p$ is that you cannot always prove the former when the implication $p \to q$ is true, while you can always prove the latter.

Ultimately, a proof of the former *requires* that $p$ be true, which doesn’t always have to be the case. For example, if you want to prove

$\forall x \in \mathbb R. \exists y \in \mathbb R. (x \not =0 \to x= \frac {1}{y})$

you *do not* want to prove

$\forall x \in \mathbb R. \exists y \in \mathbb R. \neg (x \not =0 \to x \not = \frac {1}{y})$

since it is equivalent to

$\forall x \in \mathbb R. \exists y \in \mathbb R. (x \not =0 \land x= \frac {1}{y})$

which is clearly false.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. I agree a proof the former requires that p must be true. So in that case if we know that the assumption P is always true for instance in your case it would be: $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}  \exists y \in \mathbb{R} .(x\neq 0\implies x = \frac{1}{y}) $ assume instead it is  $$\forall x \neq 0 \in\mathbb{R}  \exists y \in \mathbb{R} .(x\neq 0\implies x = \frac{1}{y}) $$ then to prove this it equivalent to show $\forall x\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R} . \exists y \in \mathbb{R} .\left(x \neq 0 \wedge x=\frac{1}{y}\right)$.

Comment: Yes, that would work even though it’s probably not the easiest way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: If you are careful about any implicit quantifiers, then a proof by this technique is valid. But it has very limited usefulness. (And now that I have re-read [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4840674/139123) I see that this point was already made, but I’ve already taken the trouble to write the answer below.)

---

The problem is that in many cases (perhaps all “interesting” cases), you cannot actually be sure that $P$ is true.

Suppose $P$ is “$3$ is even” and $Q$ is “$2$ is even.”
Then $P\implies Q$ is true.
But so is $P \implies \lnot Q$.
So you can’t prove $P\implies Q$ this way even though it’s true.

You also have to beware of quantifiers, especially implicit quantifiers.
For example, suppose $P$ is “$n$ is even” and $Q$ is “$n$ is a multiple of $6$.”
Then when we write $P\implies Q$,
we really mean, “For all $n$, $n$ is even implies $n$ is a multiple of $6$.”
This is false.
And when we write $P\implies \lnot Q$,
we really mean, “For all $n$, $n$ is even implies $n$ is not a multiple of $6$.” This also is false. For example, consider $n=6.$
But if you prove that this statement is false, you have not proved that $P\implies Q$.

To prove that $P\implies Q$ for every $n$, you would need to prove $\lnot(P\implies \lnot Q)$ for every $n.$
If you can do that, then in fact you **will** have proved $P\implies Q.$
But keep in mind that while $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to $(\lnot P) \lor Q,$
$\lnot(P\implies\lnot Q)$ is equivalent to $P\land Q,$ which is often harder to prove and never easier. This may explain why this technique is not taught.

Answer (score 1):

You said that the goal is to prove $P \Rightarrow Q$. We can't use $\lnot (P \Rightarrow \lnot Q)$ to prove $P \Rightarrow Q$ since they are not equivalent.

A proof for the forward direction would be something like:

```
If ¬(P ⇒ ¬Q):
    If P
        If ¬Q:
            If P:
                ¬Q.
            P ⇒ ¬Q.
            ¬(P ⇒ ¬Q).
            ⊥.
        ¬¬Q.
        Q.
    P ⇒ Q.
```

Now, consider the backward direction:

```
If P ⇒ Q:
    If P ⇒ ¬Q:
        If P:
            Q.
            ¬Q.
            ⊥.
        ¬P.
```

We just get that if $P \Rightarrow Q$, then if $P \Rightarrow \lnot Q$, then $\lnot P$. Hence, such a proof would be invalid.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer soupless. The question is if we know P is true for example  assume we have three angles of a triangle $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ we want to show: $x_{1} = 60,x_{2} = 60 \implies x_{3} =60$. from above I claim to show this is true need to show $x_{1} = 60,x_{2} = 60 \implies x_{3} \neq 60$ is false  which by   contrapositive means to show  $ x_{3} =  60 \implies x_{1} \neq 60\, or\, x_{2} \neq 60 $ which is false. In this case we don't care about P be False and rather we only care about when P = T which the two logical statements are the same under the assumption of P=T?

Comment: @Aria You said that we need to prove $P \Rightarrow Q$. Either we show that $Q$ is true, or $P$ is false. That's why I showed that this is impossible. If you do know that $P$ is true, then yes, they would be equivalent.